# How can I make conditional binding in knockout.js?

Tags: binding, knockout.js

I tried this one :

```
<div data-bind="attr: {class: itemSelected? 'selected' : 'unselected' }"></div>
```

But it does not work :)

Comment: Have you tried with a whitespace between itemSelected and "?"
attr: {class: itemSelected ? 'selected' : 'unselected' }

Comment: Has "whitespace" got meaning in knockout.js ?

Comment: It does when it seperates the question mark from the variable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming you have this:

```
function viewModel() {
    this.itemSelected = ko.observable(true);
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());​
```

Add a () after itemSelected to get the current value of the observable that you can use with the ternary operator:

`<div data-bind="attr: { class: itemSelected() ? 'selected' : 'unselected' }"></div>​`

http://jsfiddle.net/RK7Ty/

---

If you didn't need to assign the unselected class for the non selected state you could do this instead:

```
<div data-bind="css: { selected: itemSelected }"></div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RK7Ty/1/

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me, i was using both css and id attributes, for me it did't work if css attribute is not the first one , so keep css attribute as your fist one.

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" data-bind="css:{in:$index()==0}, attr: { id:'collapse'+$index()} ">

...
...
...

</div>
```