# if statement binding short circuiting in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to hide a span if the value is null or simply show an empty string.  The if statement is not short circuiting so I am wrapping the whole statement in a div.

Here is what I have now that is working:

```
<div data-bind="if: Allergen()"><span data-bind="text: Allergen().Name"></span></div>
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```
<span data-bind="if: Allergen(), text: Allergen().Name"></span>
```

Is there a coalesce or something in knockout?

Comment: Use a Ternary operator.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11602760

Comment: Hi, please kindly look at my small blog about short circuiting and I hope it could help a little: js-guru.blogspot.com/2015/08/javascript-short-circuiting.html

Comment: coalesce would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use virtual [if bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)

```
<!-- ko if: Allergen() -->  
<span data-bind="text: Allergen().Name"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or use [visible-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) instead (but it's not null-safe)

```
<span data-bind="visible: Allergen(), text: Allergen() ? Allergen().Name : '' "></span>
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C3NS5/)